# Writing a macro to call a menu function (edit -> text operation -> to lower case)

Tags: macros, texstudio, tex-core

I'm trying to write a macro that will automatically change the selected text to lower-case. I usually just use my keyboard and hit alt+e, t, enter quickly and it's as good as a macro for me, but I'm trying to export a package of useful macros for my co-workers.

So far I've got

```
%SCRIPT
var menu = app.getManagedMenu("main/edit");         //define "menu" as the edit menu
var enter = app.simulateKeyPress("Enter")           //define "enter" as pressing the enter key
var act = app.newManagedAction(menu, "T", enter);   //define act as opening the edit menu, pressing T to open Text Operations, and pressing enter to activate
act();                                              //acting out above
```

Error code is

```
Uncaught exception at line 3: TypeError: ambiguous call of overloaded function newManagedAction(); candidates were
    newManagedAction(QWidget*,QString,QString)
    newManagedAction(QWidget*,QString,QAction*)

Backtrace <global>() at 3
```

Could anybody help? I'm sort of learning on the job here.

I'm writing the macros in TexStudio

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with (La)TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question seems to be about javascript (?), not about TeX & friends. Try [softwareengineering.SX](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), [codereview.SX](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm writing the macro in TexStudio which I think uses QtScript. Is this not an appropriate question for here? Sorry, I'm new to the website.

Comment: Could you make it clearer in the question that you're writing TeXStudio macros? Generally on this site "macro" will be understood as TeX/LaTeX macros, so your question is quite confusing. (Unfortunately I'm not sure whether customizing TeXStudio will still be considered offtopic by the community, but at least the question will be clearer, as will its relationship to TeX/LaTeX.)